# Is a IEC C8 2 poles to IEC C5 3 poles safe to use?

Tags: power-supply, cables

I just bought a new super compact laptop and found that the power cable is disproportionately thick and has three connectors.

[image]

I would like to buy this converter and use a thinner cable with it.
Is it safe to use with my laptops charging adapter?

This is the AC Adapter: https://www.ipc-computer.de/notebook-ersatzteile/netzteile/netzteil-cp810391-xx-77391348

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is unsafe because you will be disconnecting the earth/ground pin by using that adapter.

It reads on the adapter that it must be connected to a earthed/grounded outlet.

Those adapters should not be sold because they allow you to do unsafe things. I wonder if they are even legally allowed to used for some purposes by electrical codes.

Comment: Strange, since most laptop supplies are double insulated and therefore don’t need (and I believe must not have) an earth connection.  If it’s there, though, it must be earthed so a 2-pin adapter is not acceptable.

Comment: @Frog But isn't the charger typically placed in series with the supply? What if there's a failure in the (high current) battery charger? If there's no safety ground, then it would at least seem that the charger has turned into a fire hazard.

Comment: @Frog Most laptop supplies what I see is exactly the opposite to what you see, they always have a earth/ground pin. Might depend where in the world you live, but most two pin supplies can output capacitive leakage currents enough that you might feel it while using the laptop or it can damage things when connecting equipment together.

Comment: @Lundin The earth has nothing to do with battery charging. Laptop supply input takes in isolated 20V and uses it to run the laptop and charge lithium batteries. The problem is if the power supply isolation fails and parts of the laptop becomes live with mains, and earth is used for mains input filtering and dumping the SMPS leakage currents to keep the output isolated and near ground potential.

Comment: What I meant was that I wouldn't assume that the "black box" between mains and the laptop is always just a dumb trafo, it may as well be the battery charger. And if there is a failure in the charger, it's the same problem there as if the laptop would become live with mains.

Comment: wow, i understand half of what you say. so basically an adapter like that should not be used.

Comment: @TMvytKA9LgSVZ8Z7 Correct. That adapter should not be used. It bypasses electrical safety and intended operation of the device.

Comment: is there no standard with a thinner lighter cable? but now that I think of it, it's not really that much of an issue.

Comment: Thank you guys, you're probably saving lives =)